# RPi is not finding packages libapache-mod-php5 and php5

Tags: raspbian, pi-3b+, apt, sudo

It is not finding these packages. Does anybody know why?

It is not finding the installation candidate. Here is the result of `sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 php5`:

```
pi@raspberrypi3:~ $ sudo apt-get install libapache2-mod-php5 -y
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package libapache2-mod-php5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'libapache2-mod-php5' has no installation candidate
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PHP 5 is [no longer supported](https://www.php.net/supported-versions.php).

You could use PHP 7 instead:

```sh
sudo apt install libapache2-mod-php7.3
```

Comment: @DeepCreek23 If the answer helped you so please accept it with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish your question and it will not pop up again for years (and anoying us ;-).